# Check when a login was disabled

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have auditors this week, and I'm looking for the evidence of when the sa account was disabled, but I cannot find the memo where we requested this account to be disabled. Is it possible from within SQL, to run a query where it displays when as a login disabled, i.e. date and time. My DB is a SQL 2012 version.

Thanks in advance for your asssitance.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `updatedate` returned by

`SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins`

and  assume this is when the account was disabled (but this isn't the actual disabled date). Or perhaps

`SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('sa','LockoutTime')`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However the output for the first query does not help much as after it was disabled, back in last year, it was changed this year, so the update date shows 2016 as if it was disabled this year. The second query is outputting the year of 1900, which is incorrect. I guess some formatting would help.